# How to do Fourier series, deduce question?

Tags: limits, functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

[image]

Hello,

This is a question using Fourier series to show that $t^2$ = $f(t)$ in Fourier series.

I could do the Fourier series part but I am not sure how to do the `deduce` = $\pi^2/3$ part of the question?

Could somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Can you find two expressions for $f(0)$?

---

We have $f(t)=t^2$ and $f(t)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}+4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2}\cos(nt)$ and they give the same value for $t=0$. Then after equating these two expression, re-arrange and deduce that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}.$

Comment: If I set $t$ = 0, wouldn't $cos(nt)$ = 1, but I am stuck as to how that would contribute to the $-1^{n+1}$

Comment: Yes, I've added above.

Comment: omg, I completely forgot about the -$\frac{\pi^{2}}{3}$, on the left hand side.